# Issue with Drawing 2D Textures

Tags: monogame, texture2d

I'm using these spritebatch.begin arguements

```
    spriteBatch.Begin(WorldManager.Instance.currentWorld.camera, SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, SamplerState.PointClamp, null, null);
    spriteBatch.Draw(texture: animations[i].textures, position: positions[i], color: Color.White, sourceRectangle: animations[i].currentTexturesBounds);
    spriteBatch.End();
```

[image: that's what i should be getting]

[image: and that's what im getting]

iam using the Camero library for the camera (as you can see the first arguement is a camera) to Zoom

Comment: What exactly is the problem with what you're getting? The background?

Comment: some of the player's pixels are smaller than others you can compare the player in the 2 images one in the paint.NET ( the first one) and the other in the game ( the second one)

Comment: Please post the actual line that draws the sprite, you seem to have some scaling in there. Maybe you're scaling the sprite or the size of the backbuffer does not match your window. Do you have a window with border? Are you using the correct Width/Height of the window? (ClientWidth and ClientHeight I think)

Comment: iam not scaling it the camero library is it has a camera that someone suggested so i can zoom and i dont know what do you mean with the back buffer anyways ill add code to the question

Comment: You're setting only the position and viewport of the camera, so even if you zoom in or out, the scale of your sprite won't change. *EDIT* not even that, you're just setting values used for drawing details. Get a camera matrix and put it inside a `spriteBatch.Begin` method call. Should be okay. Don't remember if that should be inverted though.

Comment: in the spriteBatch.begin i add the camera as an arguement i think that what do the scale to everything in it

Comment: Seems to be correct, do you have a zoom activated? How are you initializing the window? Do you use the basic Game window or do you have your own initialization code?

Comment: i have only edited the window size and yes the camera have zoom in it

Comment: and yes it scales this is without the camera
https://i.imgur.com/LobqPzc.png
and this is with the camera
https://i.imgur.com/r3EPiP2.png
in the spritebatch

Comment: Yeah so it's the camera's zoom that leads to pixels being of different size. This usually happens when a "bad" scaling-algorithm is used (eg. next neighbour), I think. Check if Camero has something equal to the SamplerState option of SpriteBatch.Begin. Also try setting SpriteBatch.Begin to AnisotropicClamp

Comment: https://github.com/aloisdeniel/Comora/tree/master/Sources/Comora
iam really not good in XNA so i dont know what to search for here's the source of the library i even spelled it wrong its comora

Comment: I checked the code and I think setting SamplerState.AnisotropicClamp instead of SamplerState.PointClamp in Begin should suffice, have you tried yet?

Comment: yes and its blurry same as linearClamp

Comment: Okay, don't know then. Try null as SamplerState (or don't set it at all), null is the default setting according to the code.

Comment: the default is linearclamp which is blurry ;-;

Comment: It's either blurry or blocky, if you don't want it blurry, you need to watch the  zoom-factor so the pixels all scale the same. Try zoom=2, all pixels should have the same size.

Comment: oh thanks that did work you can write it as an answer